# All characteristic subgroups are normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, characteristic-subgroups

How do I prove that all characteristic subgroups $H\subset G$ are normal?
I tried to prove that $gHg^{-1}\subset \sigma [H]$ and that $\sigma [H]\subset gHg^{-1}$, but this isn't working out.

Comment: Inner automorphisms are, in particular, automorphisms, so being stable by all automorphisms implies being stable by inner automorphisms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to think of normal subgroups is as subgroups which are invariant under **inner** automorphisms. Since characteristic subgroups are invariant under **all** automorphisms, they are clearly invariant under inner automorphisms, hence normal.

Comment: i get that, but isnt there a more formal way of proving this?

Comment: For arbitrary $x\in G$, let $\varphi_x$ be the automorphism $\varphi_x(g) = xgx^{-1}$. Since $H$ is a characteristic subgroup, $\varphi_x(H) = H$. In other words, $xHx^{-1}=H$  for all $x\in G$.