# $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $\phi(H) = H$ $\forall \phi \in Aut(G) \Rightarrow $ $H$ is normal in $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $\phi(H) = H$  $\forall \phi \in Aut(G) \Rightarrow $ $H$ is normal in $G$

I'm not sure where to begin. 
Perhaps we can use this corollary of the First Isomorphism Theorem 
 $N_G(H)/C_G(H) \cong Aut(H)$

But I'm not sure if this is helpful.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1215584/all-characteristic-subgroups-are-normal?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$h\mapsto ghg^{-1}$$
is an automorphism for all $g\in G$.

Comment: We can show that $ghg^{-1}$ is in $H$ by the fact that every automorphism in $Aut(G)$ will be $\phi(H) = H$. Am I correct?

Comment: @jd94: You are absolutely right :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\operatorname{Inn}(G)\le\operatorname{Aut}(G).$$

Comment: We in fact have the same answer, but your answer is more for expert (so (+1) anyway :-))

Comment: Thank you, @Surb; yours cuts to the chase though (+1).